# Add class to table th if input range value matches th id

Tags: jquery, html

Firstly let me apologise for my poor attempt at writing jQuery. I am a designer by trade.

I have a table and would like to add an active class to a `<th>` when a range input value matches the `<th>` id.

HTML:

```
<input type="range" name="levels" min="1" max="9" />
<table id="levels">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>*</th>
            <th id="1">Bronze</th>
            <th id="2">Silver</th>
            <th id="3">Gold</th>
            <th id="4">Platinum</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

jQuery so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[type=range]').change(function() {
        var rangeval = $(this).val();
        var th = $("levels th");
        //$("#1").addClass(rangeval);

        if (th.attr("id") == rangeval) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

I realise I would need to also unset the active class on change but I'm just trying to get jQuery to add a class first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=range]').change(function() {
        var rangeval = $(this).val();
        $('#levels th').removeClass();
        $('#levels th#' + rangeval).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/n0cfdxup/12/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use an `if` statement for this as you can build the id selector from the value of the range `input`. Try this:

```
$('[type=range]').change(function() {
    $('th').removeClass('active').filter('#' + this.value).addClass('active');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/b7oa59m3/)

Note that the above removes the `active` class which was previously set on any elements so that only one can be shown as active at a time.

Answer (score 0):

u are using ID selector, so should be something like

```
var th = $("#levels th");
```

otherwise it will regard it as a tag name.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `id` selector for `levels` is correct.

Then, you can do the following:

- remove all active classes from the `th`'s
- add and `active` class to the one that matches the selected value

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[type=range]').change(function() {
          var rangeval = $(this).val();

          // remove 'm all
         $("#levels th").removeClass('active');

          // add active
          $("#levels th#" + rangeval).addClass('active');

      });
  });
  ```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rLn0w77j/1/